# Manipulate not working with large numbers

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Why isn't `Manipulate[]` working with large numbers?
For instance this works

```
Manipulate[k, {k, 0, 1000000000, 1}]
```

and this doesn't

```
Manipulate[k, {k, 0, 10000000000, 1}]
```

I believe that there should be some Mathematica variable which affects this but I cannot find one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a known bug with `Manipulate` and `Slider`, specifically when there are more than `2^31` discrete "steps" for the slider.

As a workaround, you could do the following, for example:

```
Manipulate[Round[k], {k, 0, 10^100}]
```

By not specifying the step size (fourth argument), you allow the slider to set non-integer values for the variable, but you can get around this by using `Round` (or `IntegerPart`).

Hope that helps!